# AppScript. Will linked GCP project affect quota?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, quota, google-cloud-logging

I'm confused with one moment regarding GCP. So, i have different AppScript projects on different google accounts and i want to link them to single GCP project (on organization level) to be able to see logs in single place (followed this [description](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)). Everything work fine, but i don't understand now if it will affect quota somehow. From my understanding quota described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) is per user, but i just worry that i missed something and because of the linked GCP project quota will be splitted between all appscript project.
I would appreciate any help and advice related to this question)

Comment: Is there a specific quota limit you are concerned about? I think quotas described at [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) apply per script project, and it doesn't matter that they are linked to the same GCP project, while API-specific quotas, like https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits, do apply to the GCP project.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm concern about spreadsheets read/write quota, but i don't fully understand difference between using SheetsAPI and [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) in terms of quota. Do you think SpreasheetApp operations affect quota in the same way as a requests to SheetsApi from some beckend application?

Comment: As far as my experience goes, `SpreadsheetApp` methods don't affect Sheets API quota (by contrast, [Advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) does affect). Therefore, I'll upvote the answer posted by roma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any limit to read/write operations for sheets using apps script, there's nothing about it in quotas and it doesn't make much sense.

There are quotas if you use Sheets Api via http
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

but that's entirely other story, and you only need this to access sheets from other environments(nodejs,php,python etc)

If you're using apps script I believe you're only limited by script runtime and total trigger runtime, which are counted per-script.